# How to minify Browserify output with npm scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, uglifyjs

I saw a lot of reference on how to do it on command line and also using gulp. But how can i do the same using package.json scripts. I mean something like this?

```
"scripts": {
    "build" : "browserify ./js/app.js | uglify -o ./dist/bundle.js",
    "watch" : "watchify ./js/app.js -o ./dist/bundle.js --debug --verbose"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts": {
    "minify:js" : "browserify ./js/app.js && uglifyjs ./js/app.js -o ./dist/bundle.js",
    "watch" : "watchify ./js/app.js -o ./dist/bundle.js --debug --verbose"
    },
```

After that run

```
npm run minify:js
```

Comment: please mention reason before downvoting.